# User settings (Access DB)

Tags: ms-access, path

I'm making several local Access Databases, for several users. The databases are not shared - they're independent from each other.
Every time I make some modifications to the DBs - I'm making them on my own DB (on my computer) and then copying the database to other users' computers.

Some of the forms and reports display images based on absolute paths (recorded in a table's fields). Relative paths don't work. The Reports are exported to PDF also based on an absolute path (in macros). Each time I'm copying the database to someone's computer I have to change manually all these paths.

I would like to add an Initial Configuration Form - so that the user would indicate his particular absolute path, which should be then recorded into the table's fields and used by the Macros to save to PDF.

What's the proper way of doing that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you should start linking to at least one backend table.  For your initial configuration, I would suggest a User/Path configuration table, that would be able to look up each user's particular path.  Use DLOOKUP and perhaps use the user's windows USERNAME as the key.

Comment: Thank you, geeFlo! Does DLOOKUP return values from non-linked tables? I've read an article on DLOOKUP but it doesn't state clear whether it does or don't. The structure of the expression looks like it doesn't matter - are the tables linked or not

Comment: It works just great! Thank you, geeFlo! The tables don't have to be linked - that's the best thing about this expression! The user/path table existed - but as this table wasn't linked with the others I didn't see the way to extract the path from there.

Comment: If the data exists locally on each person's copy, then you're correct it doesn't need to be "linked."   I was referring more to a centralized local table, where you could actually store everybody's information, thus avoiding having to go to and change local copies each time you make changes.  Glad to hear it's working good enough for you.

Comment: I understand now. However, the DB is designed to act as independent local copies - not bind to any networks. thanks again!